# React Formik form not dirty after array value update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am trying to use [Formik](https://formik.org/docs/overview) in my React app for handling form state for an array of checkboxes.

When a checkbox gets clicked, I create a copy from the old values, toggle the checked value of the one that got clicked and use `setFieldValue` to update the value with the new array.

I would like to render something based on the `dirty` value but it is never true.

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-chaum-99bus1?file=/src/App.js)

```js
import { Formik, Form } from "formik";

const Checkbox = ({ label, onClick, checked }) => {
  return <div onClick={onClick}>{label}: {JSON.stringify(checked)}</div>;
};

const options = [{ value: "first", checked: false }, { value: "second", checked: true }];
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Formik initialValues={{ checkboxValues: options }} onSubmit={(values) => {console.log(values)}}>
      {({ values, dirty, setFieldValue }) => (
        <Form>
          {values.checkboxValues.map((v, i) => {
            return (
              <Checkbox key={v.value} label={v.value} checked={v.checked}
                onClick={() => {
                  const optionsCopy = [...values.checkboxValues];
                  optionsCopy[i].checked = !optionsCopy[i].checked;
                  setFieldValue("checkboxValues", optionsCopy);
                }}
              />
            );
          })}
          <button type="submit">submit</button>
          {dirty ? <p>dirty</p> : <p>clean</p>}
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}
```

Comment: In your Sandbox example, state is dirty when any of these two Checkbox components are clicked. In SO example, you set same form value again, in Sandbox example you set different checkbox form value

Comment: Yes I just found the solution in the sandbox, will add it here.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. I tried out with array as a value for one form property, and it does not make `dirty` true... That could be nice to fix also.

Comment: @MarioPetrovic it is confusing to me as well, in following link, there is a similar case with object but then it works if you make a copy so I thought this would work with an array as well https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1148#issuecomment-496223224

Comment: Not sure why it rerenders the form, but does not put flag dirty as true...

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, the `optionsCopy` array created inside the `onClick` function is not triggering a re-render.

Setting `checkboxValues` field directly fixes the issue.

```js
onClick={() => {
  setFieldValue(
    `checkboxValues.${i}.checked`,
    !values.checkboxValues[i].checked
  );
}}
```